# How can I change update into updateIn when I use immutable.js

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to make my code neat by using immutable.js.

But I don't know how to replace the update into updateIn. Please help me.

```
[SET_COLOR]: (state, action) => {
  const counters = state.get("counters");
  const { color, index } = action.payload;

  return state.set(
    "counters",
    counters.updateIn([index, "color"], color => /*I got stuck here*/ )
  );
}
```

I've tried {color}, ({color}), color, color = color...

This is the original one.

```
const initialState = Map({
  counters: List([
    Map({
      number: 0,
      color: "black"
    })
  ])
});

(...)

[SET_COLOR]: (state, action) => {
  const counters = state.get("counters");
  const { color, index } = action.payload;

  return state.set(
    "counters",
    counters.update(index, counter => counter.set("color", color))
  );
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [setIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/setIn) instead:

```
[SET_COLOR]: (state, action) => {
  const { color, index } = action.payload;

  return state.setIn(["counters", index, "color"], color);
}
```

`updateIn` would only be useful if the updated value depended on the current value located at the path supplied to `updateIn`. For example:

```
const immutableObject = Immutable.fromJS({ outerProp: { innerCount: 1 } }); 
immutableObject.updateIn(['outerProp', 'innerCount'], count => count + 1);
```

Comment: Wow.. exactly what I waited for... I really appreciate :D 
I want to give you a point, but I can't do that because of my lower reputation. Thx!!

Comment: @BWYWB00 you can still accept the answer if it answered your question correctly. Glad it helped!